# DB2 procedure call literal error

Tags: db2, procedure

I'm trying to call a DB2 procedure using DBeaver.
The syntax I'm using is this:

```
{ call db.procedure_name ('1234','2345','3456') }
```

Then I get an error saying:

> "Literal replacement prasing failed for procedure call... Failing SQL
>   text..."

When I call the same procedure like this:

```
{ call db.procedure_name (?,?,?) }
```

and insert the parameters manually it executes.
I'm quite new to DB2 and IBM troubleshooting sites aren't much of a help.
Can you guys help me out? Thanks.

Comment: That syntax with literals works correctly for me with DBeaver 5.1.2 and Db2-LUW when submitted from the SQL-Editor.   What's your versions and environment?

Answer (score 0):

Try `call db.procedure_name (:1,:2,:3)`
or alternatively, create global variables for each parameter

```
 create or replace variable p1 integer default 123;
 create or replace variable p2 decimal(5,2) default 123.45;
 create or replace variable p3 char(5);
 set p3 = '12345';
 call db.procedure_name (p1,p2,p3);
```